# Laravel - Mailing system doesn't work on my Web server but gives cURL error 7: (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Tags: laravel, mailgun, guzzle

I am using Mailgun to send mail and It works well on my local server, but on my Web Server, where the site is hosted on HackFlix, It produces this error after sending

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException
>
> > cURL error 7: (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

I have done many research to this problem and i didn't get any correct answer that solves cURL error 7. Some people say that i should ping or nslookup smtp.mailgun.org but I don't have SSH shell access on my server. Please, what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: I've found the answer. The reason for this situation( cURL error 7) is a security measure of the outgoing connection filter. So, It was not activated in the setting of HackFlix Control Panel. They showed me the way to activate outgoing connections in advanced settings. Now, it is fixed